# Two apps extend from the same base.html in Django

Tags: django

I have two apps. Both have different base.html templates that index.html extends from. The index.html is different though on each app.

But for some reason it only extends from the same app with base.html? How is this possible?

This is how it looks in both of my my index.html templates:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your `template/` directory structure set up? If an `index.html` template extends from `base.html`, Django will choose whatever `base.html` is in your root template directory.

Solution:
Either rename one of your `base.html` templates to something like `base2.html` and put it in `templates/` alongside `base1.html`, or create new directories in `templates/` to put the `base.html` files into.

For solution A, make sure you change `{% extends base.html %}` to `{% extends base2.html %}` in the appropriate `index.html` template.

For solution B, your `base.html` files would keep the same name, but be in different directories. So one is in say `templates/base1/base.html` and the other is in `templates/base2/base.html`. Your `index.html` files would extend like `{% extends base1/base.html %}` and `{% extends base2/base.html %}`. Note that all extension paths are relative to the root of your chosen template directory.

IMO solution B is better as it separates the code for each template base into different, explicitly named folders. Better organization/flexibility and less confusion for you in the future.

Comment: If I have different base.html for different apps, can we just put the respective base in the template root of that particular app